# If a random variable $Z$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma{Y})$ for some random vector $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, then it is of the form $g\circ Y$

Tags: probability-theory

I've encountered this claim at the beginning of a course on stochastic processes but no reference or proof is given and I can't see why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** Suppose $Z=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\boldsymbol 1_{A_i}$ is simple. Let $B_i\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $A_i=Y^{-1}(B_i)$. Then, $$g(x):=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\boldsymbol 1_{B_i}$$ is a measurable s.t. $Z=g(Y)$.

**Step 2:** Suppose $Z\geq 0$ being $\sigma (Y)-$measurable. There is a sequence $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of $\sigma (Y)-$measurable functions s.t. $Z_n\nearrow Z$. By the first step, there is $g_n:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ measurable s.t. $Z_n=g_n(Y)$. Then $$g(x):=\limsup_{n\to \infty }g_n(x)$$
is s.t. $Z=g(Y)$.

**Step 3:** If $Z$ is only $\sigma (Y)$ measurable, then you can write it as $Z^+-Z^-$ where $Z^+:=Z\vee 0$ and $Z^-:=-(Z\wedge 0)$ and apply the Step 2.